# Is it possible to tail a log with a cursor?

Tags: sql-server, cursors

I thought the DYNAMIC keyword would work but it doesn't seem to. Basically I have an ASP.NET Application using the log4net [AdoNetAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html). I'd like to be able to SELECT * FROM Logging.Logging in a cursor and have it keep reading new columns inserted after I opened the cursor.

I know I could just keep sending `SELECT * FROM Logging.Log WHERE Id > @LastLogId` and sleeping. That seems like not the optimal method.

Do I need to set transaction isolation to something other than the default for the cursor to see the changes?

This is my current code:

```
USE AlwaysEncryptedSample;
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE 
    @Date CHAR(19),
    @Thread VARCHAR(255),
    @Level VARCHAR(50),
    @Logger VARCHAR(255),
    @User NVARCHAR(50),
    @ClientIP NVARCHAR(45),
    @Message VARCHAR(4000),
    @Exception VARCHAR(2000),
    @Severity INT;
PRINT '-------- Log4netLog --------'

DECLARE curLog CURSOR DYNAMIC FORWARD_ONLY 
    FOR 
        SELECT
                FORMAT([Date],'g'), Thread, [Level], Logger,
                [User], ClientIP, [Message], Exception,
                CASE
                    WHEN [Level] = 'Debug' OR [Level] = 'Info' THEN 0
                    WHEN [Level] = 'Warning' THEN 10
                    ELSE 16
                END 
            FROM Logging.Log
            --WHERE Date > GETDATE();
OPEN curLog;

FETCH NEXT FROM curLog
    INTO 
    @Date, 
    @Thread,
    @Level,
    @Logger,
    @User,
    @ClientIP, 
    @Message,
    @Exception,
    @Severity

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN; 
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 RAISERROR('%s - %s - %s', @Severity, 1, @Date, @Level, @Message) WITH NOWAIT;
    ELSE
    BEGIN;
        SET @Date = FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'g')
        RAISERROR('%s - NULL - No Log written sleeping for 5 seconds', 0, 1, @Date) WITH NOWAIT;
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
    END; 
    FETCH NEXT FROM curLog INTO 
        @Date, 
        @Thread,
        @Level,
        @Logger,
        @User,
        @ClientIP, 
        @Message,
        @Exception,
        @Severity
END;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a cursor takes a snapshot of the data that is return from the query.  This [three part guide](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/05/truth-about-cursors-part-1.html) has helped me in the past understand the differences in the cursor declarations.

Comment: I think the `SELECT * FROM Logging.Log WHERE Id > @LastLogId` method will be most efficient if you have a clustered primary key index on `Id`.